# Payment Dates of Microsoft Store Subscription Add-on

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

How do you determine when payments were made for a monthly subscription add-on for an app in the Microsoft Store?

We wish to offer subscription add-ons to our app through the Microsoft Store. We offer the user a statement which shows when payments were made and how credit was consumed in the app.

The app works offline. When the user comes online after being offline for a period, we need to be able to check the date at which their monthly subscription was paid for each month since they were last online.

We know when the initial payment was made as the payment is made from within the app, but the exact date in the month that Microsoft debits a user's account can vary slightly from month to month.

We can tell when a user comes back online if the subscription is current by `storeProduct.IsInUserCollection` but I can't see how to determine payment dates.

Is there a way to interrogate the Microsoft Store from within the app to determine the date of each monthly payment?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to interrogate the Microsoft Store from within the app to determine the date of each monthly payment?

Currently, there is no such API being able to get the specific date and time when Microsoft charges user's credit card. We usually use **[Windows Store collection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/query-for-products)** to scope the query for the info to specific app/add-on product. But subscription add-on currently is not included in the supported add-on type for this API.

According to **[Get subscription for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user)**, we still cannot get this value through Microsoft Store purchase API.

Also, subscription add-ons are currently not available to most developer accounts. **[Some features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app#unsupported-scenarios)** might not be supported to this type of add-on now. Thus, if you have feature request, you could post your feedback to **[Windows Developer User Voice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform)** site.

Comment: Thank you for the info @Zhendong Wu - MSFT but we have already created a number of subscription add-ons and we are able to retrieve details of those add-ons. We have also stepped through the process of purchasing a subscription add-on from within the app. From what you say this should not be possible. Have I misunderstood you?

Comment: I mean not all the developers' accounts could create this type of add-on. So your account has been provisioned by Microsoft to be able to create subscription add-on. But currently there's no method to get the charging date and time.

Comment: So it seems @Zhendong Wu - MSFT that most developers do not have access to subscription add-ons. There is a rest api that allows developers to get more info about their store products, but even though we do have access to subscription add-ons, we do not have access to the rest api. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: @Value The rest API can only be used by the dev whose account has been provisioned able to create subscription add-on. So you have access to it but it doesn't provide the MSFT's charging time but the add-on's `startTime` and expiration time

Comment: Thanks for the info @Zhendong Wu - MSFT. As we are able to create subscription add-ons we should be able to use the rest api. The rest api requires 'An Azure AD access token that was created with the https://onestore.microsoft.com audience URI.' https://onestore.microsoft.com doesn't seems to exist, so how do we get an Azure AD access token?